# Workflow error "The workflow failed validation."

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a Sequential workflow with a Policy Rule . When I run from the client, I get the following error:
"The workflow failed validation."
Activity 'policyActivity1' validation failed: Can not find the rule set "Rule Set1". Check if rule set is defined in the rules file.
Can anyone point me in the right direction....

Comment: Did you find a fix without changing to console client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Sequential Workflow project with the Console client, not a library project. Deleted the Program.cs file and found that the only difference between the library project and the new one I created was that the new one had this Workflow in a designer file while the library file dealth with xoml file. This fixed the problem for me....